# Почему не добавляется JScrollPanel к JTextAre

Tags: java

Пытаюсь добавить к JTextArea JScrollPanel, в чем ошибка и как ее исправить?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

class Okno extends JFrame {


    private final JPanel panel;
    private final JButton button;
    private JTextArea area;
    private final JTextField textArea;

    public Okno() {
        setSize(400, 1000);
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("Простые числа");

        button = new JButton();
        button.setActionCommand("Go");
        button.setText("Посчитать");
        button.addActionListener(e -> buttonPressed(e));
        button.setBounds(10,500,230,60);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(area);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(area);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        area = new JTextArea(5,10);
        area.setText("Тут будут циферки");
        area.setBounds(250,10,120,940);
        area.setLineWrap(true);
        area.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        area.setEditable(false);

        textArea = new JTextField(10);
        textArea.setText("");
        textArea.setBounds(10,400,230,60);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(textArea);
        panel.add(area);
        panel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);



        setContentPane(panel);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void buttonPressed(ActionEvent e) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            int k = Integer.parseInt(textArea.getText());
            for (int i = 2; i < k; i++) {
                int count = 0;
                for (int j = 2; j <= i && count < 2; ++j) {
                    if (i % j == 0) count++;
                }
                if (count < 2) sb.append(i).append("\n");
            }
            area.setText(String.valueOf(sb));
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Okno.this,
                    "Некорректный ввод данных","Ошибка"
                    , JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(area);`
Здесь area ещё равна null.
Нужно сначала проинициализировать переменную area.

Answer (score 0):

Так как здесь нет Panel Layout = null
То нужно указывать где должна быть scrollpanel

```
 scrollPane.setBounds(250,10,120,940);
```